# Using UUID vs @Id annotation in spring project

Tags: java, spring

I'm very new to Spring/Springboot and have seen different approaches in tutorials regarding the model classes used to represent database objects. I was just wondering when it's appropriate to use which?

**Approach 1:**

A basic class to model a user object

```
public class User {

    private final UUID id;
    // other fields

    public User(UUID id, <other fields>) {
    this.id = id;
    // set other fields
}
```

In the repository layer, we might have a DAO which looks something like

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao {

    public int createUser(UUID id, <other fields>);

    // other CRUD operations    
}
```

When the user doesn't input a valid UUID (or absent) a default method could insert it by calling `UUID.randomUUID()`

**Approach 2:**

Instead of using a UUID as a unique identifier, instead, with something like Hibernate/JPA we use the @Entity annotation on the User class in the model package, and have the PK field annotated with @Id

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private final long id;

    // other fields
}
```

Comment: using long as id will help you to save database capacity

Answer (score 0):

@Id annotation is the most commonly used approach in Hibernate. This will map a Java String / BigDecimal / long attribute to an identifier. And using this, you can use specify four generation strategies - AUTO, IDENTITY, SEQUENCE and TABLE.

UUIDs are used when you want your primary key to be globally unique. I can think of a few scenarios where you might want this -

- You have data in multiple databases and your keys needs to be unique across different databases.
- You need your generated id value even before you persist your record in your database for specific business purposes.

But the downside is that, UUIDs are long and may cost more in terms of storage space.